# Strange compiler error when trying to construct std::thread:

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

The following program fails to compile with  `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror test.cpp -o test.o`:

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void fill(int n) {
    return;
}

int main() {
    thread test(fill, 5);
}
```

```
test.cpp:9:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'
    thread test(fill, 5);
           ^    ~~~~~~~
```

Is it because `fill` is conflicting with `std::fill` from `#include <algorithm>`? I haven't included this but I suppose `<thread>` might've.

Changing my function name to `fillie` (or anything else pretty much) allows it to compile correctly without linking `pthread`.

I ask because it is a strange compiler error message, and also it means that the thread constructor can't disambiguate which function I am using based on the parameters (which sort of makes sense, but wanted confirmation).

Comment: That would fix a linker error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Yet another reason `using namespace std;` is a terrible idea.

Comment: I've edited my original post to make it clear that I was able to compile it correctly by changing the function name.

Comment: `using namespace std;` strikes again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the problem is because it is not known whether `fill` is `std::fill` or your global `fill` function.

One way to fix it is to write `::fill` to explicitly use the global one.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something like this but I didn't know how to test it. Looks like `::fill` is my answer, and also potentially using namespaces/classes`.

Comment: @VishaalKalwani — re: “potentially using namespaces “ — the standard library already uses namespaces. This code blows them away with `using namespace std;`. Just don’t do that.

Comment: I meant putting my own code behind a namespace, but you are right, I’ll avoid the std full namespace one. This code was for a timed interview problem so I thought it’d save me time, but alas, I was wrong